# I am trying to convert deeply nested JSON into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert a json returned from the API call into pandas dataframe. Ideally I would like to extract only 'Type','Name' and 'SUPPLY'.

I have tried multiple things, such as `flatten()`, `json_normalize()` and so on, but couldn't make it to work.

```
def get_cryptocompare_data():
    url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?limit=15&tsym=USD"
    data = requests.get(url)
    d = data.json()
```

I would like to convert it to pandas dataframe, with columns for 'Type','Name','SUPPLY'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the old way (`for` loop) when dealing with heavily nested JSON like this because it is simple to understand.

```
import pandas as pd

records = []

for item in d["Data"]:
    records.append(
        {
            "Type": item["CoinInfo"]["Type"],
            "Name": item["CoinInfo"]["Name"],
            "SUPPLY": item["RAW"]["USD"]["SUPPLY"],
        }
    )


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)

df.head()
```

I don't set the `Type` as the index because i'm not sure why you want `Type` as the index since it only has 1 value. If you need to set `Type` as the index, just add `df.set_index("Type", inplace=True)`

Comment: Thank you @pythonjokeun for your solution. It worked perfectly for me. I apologize for the confusion, but I didn't realize that Type is always 1.

Answer (score 1):

[Jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) could help here with nested paths - basic summary is if u encounter a list, represent it with a bracket(`[]`), if it is a key, access it wih dot notation (`.`) :

```
import requests
url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?limit=15&tsym=USD"
data = requests.get(url).json()

#example : access the name key :
#path : Data -> list -> CoinInfo(dict) ->Name(dict)
#representation : Data[].CoinInfo.Name
#in words : Data, then list, then CoinInfo key, then Name key

import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile('''{name:Data[].CoinInfo.Name,
                                  type:Data[].CoinInfo.Type,
                                  supply:Data[].RAW.USD.SUPPLY}''')
res = expression.search(data)
```

Read in data

```
pd.DataFrame(res)

    name    type    supply
0   BTC     1   1.833352e+07
1   ETH     1   1.105811e+08
2   XRP     1   9.999185e+10
3   GAPS    1   2.000000e+09
4   CRO     1   1.000000e+11
5   USDT    1   4.642367e+09
6   BCH     1   1.838416e+07
7   PLF     1   1.000000e+10
8   CTAG    1   4.000000e+09
9   LINK    1   1.000000e+09
```

Comment: This is a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

The goal here is to flatten `data.json()` which is a `dict` returned by `requests`.

Flattening dictionaries is a reasonable complex topic because of the various types of values that can be found within.  But here, the data feed is known.

Therefore, a simply flattening function can be found from various python recipes and functionally applied to the data obtained from the data feed.

```
import json
import itertools
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

def get_cryptocompare_data():
    url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?limit=15&tsym=USD"
    response = requests.get(url)
    d = response.json()
    return d

# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/flatten-dictionary-in-python-functional-style
def flatten_dict(d):
    def items():
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue
            else:
                yield key, value

    return dict(items())

d = get_cryptocompare_data()
data = d['Data']
data = list(map(flatten_dict, data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df[['CoinInfo.Name', 'CoinInfo.Type', 'RAW.USD.TYPE', 'RAW.USD.SUPPLY', 'DISPLAY.USD.SUPPLY']])
```

Will provide the following name, type and supply columns

```
  CoinInfo.Name  CoinInfo.Type RAW.USD.TYPE  RAW.USD.SUPPLY    DISPLAY.USD.SUPPLY
0           BTC              1            5    1.764898e+07        Ƀ 17,648,975.0
1           XRP              1            5    9.999185e+10  XRP 99,991,850,794.0
2           ETH              1            5    1.056861e+08       Ξ 105,686,063.1
3           EOS              1            5    1.041886e+09   EOS 1,041,886,454.0
4           BCH              1            5    1.764895e+07      BCH 17,648,946.0
5           LTC              1            5    6.136893e+07        Ł 61,368,933.6
6           BNB              1            5    1.883456e+08     BNB 188,345,602.2
7          USDT              1            5    2.468906e+09     ₮ 2,468,905,774.0
8           XLM              1            5    1.932851e+10  XLM 19,328,512,453.0
9           ADA              1            5    2.592707e+10  ADA 25,927,070,538.0
```